# "Attempted to read or write protected memory.." error when CrViewer print button is clicked

Tags: memory, printing, crystal-reports, protected

I am getting the error "Attempted to read or write protected memory.." on print button click of the Crystal Report Viewer. This error is random and sometimes the report prints without any errors. Sometimes it gives error as "Handle is invalid". I have tried 2-3 solutions provided on internet like un-checking the "Suppress JIT optimization.."option , but nothing has worked for me. Please help!! (Other details : Crystal Reports 2011, Crystal Reports for VS2010 version 13.0.2, C# 2010 winforms application)

Comment: What is size of your report print.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem on Windows7 64-bit only, and the `Windows6.1-KB2695321-v2-x64` hotfix solved the problem.

I used Windows Hotfix Downloader to download the hotfix.

I hope this helps.

Comment: i am sorry i discovered that  the solution  I suggested was temporary  the error come back after one day i noticed that any update you apply on windows 64 os solve the problem temporary this means that there is  a service cause the problem and this service is turned off when applying updates i wish this help

Answer (score 0):

I used this way to avoid this problem :

1. set show print button to false in crystal report viewer
2. add a custom button to toolstrip look the link below :
   http://www.manjuke.com/2011/08/invoke-custom-method-when-crystal.html
3. set Eventhandler to new customized button and inside it set code to print directly to printer

   ```
   cr1.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
   ```

when you print directly to printer the problem does not appear.
or you can create a printdialog and use it to print your report 
I did that and it all work fine